# What is wrong in the following Make File

Tags: git, makefile

Hello I am new to MakeFile so getting nothing while running the following MakeFile.

```
assign.pdf:assign.svg
    inkscape -D -A assign.pdf assign.svg
.git:assign.svg assign.pdf
    git init
:assign.pdf assign.svg .git
    git add assign.pdf assign.svg
:assign.pdf assign.svg .git
    git commit -m "File Added to git repositry"
```

The purpose of this makefile is to first generate the .pdf from .svg using inkscape and then generate the git repositry and add these file into the git.

It's only generating the pdf file and not doing anything else.

If anyone know.. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you tell it to do otherwise, `make` builds just the first target defined in the makefile, which in this makefile is `assign.pdf`.

Usually, you put a target like `all` as the first target in the makefile:

```
all: .git assign.svg assign.pdf

.git:
    git init
```

The rule lines:

```
:assign.pdf assign.svg .git
    git add assign.pdf assign.svg
:assign.pdf assign.svg .git
    git commit -m "File Added to git repositry"
```

are puzzling.  There is no target to the left of the colon; I'm not sure when, if ever, they'd be recognized and acted on.

It appears that you are checking in the derived file, `assign.pdf`.  There are times when that is necessary, but you should seldom do it.

I'm not clear what workflow you are trying to model.  It might be: if `assign.svg` has changed since the last time `assign.pdf` was created, rebuild `assign.pdf` and ensure that both `assign.svg` and `assign.pdf` are up to date in the repository.  If so, then you could use:

```
assign.pdf: assign.svg
    inkscape -D -A assign.pdf assign.svg
    git add assign.pdf assign.svg
    git commit -m 'Automatic commit of assign.pdf and assign.svg' assign.pdf assign.svg
```

You should probably plan on using macros a lot more, but getting this much right first is also a good idea.